# Stormcrawler: Injecting new URL to crawl without restarting the topology

Tags: apache, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

Is there any way to inject new URL to crawl without stoping the topology from command line and editing 
proper files ? I want to do that with Elasticsearch as indexer

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you use as a backend for storing the status of the URLs. If the URLs are stored in Elasticsearch in the *status* index, you won't need to restart the crawl topology. You can use the injector topology separately in local mode to inject the new URLs into the status index.

This is also the case with the SOLR or SQL modules but not with MemorySpout + MemoryStatusUpdater as it lives within the JVM and nowhere else.

Which spout do you use?

Comment: I am using MemorySpout and as indexing backend Elasticsearch.
Is there any tutorial how to setup status index ? Is that the original one from source code ?

Comment: The memory spout is mainly useful for debugging and quick prototyping. See https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUuzkdeQV-XEPUq53bH_b5A for a tutorial on how to use ES + SC